# What is Unobtrusive Javascript in layman terms?

Tags: javascript, unobtrusive-javascript

What is Unobtrusive Javascript in layman terms? An example would be nice to aid my understanding.

Comment: Wikipedia has good article : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Checkout the wikipedia article:

- [Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)

> "Unobtrusive JavaScript" is a general
>   approach to the use of JavaScript in
>   web pages. Though the term is not
>   formally defined, its basic principles
>   are generally understood to include:
>
> - Separation of functionality (the "behavior layer") from a Web page's
>     structure/content and presentation
> - Best practices to avoid the problems of traditional JavaScript
>     programming (such as browser
>     inconsistencies and lack of
>     scalability)
> - Progressive enhancement to support user agents that may not
>     support advanced JavaScript
>     functionality[2]

So it is basically separating behavior or javascript from presentation or html.

**Example:**

```
<input type="button" id="btn" onclick="alert('Test')" />
```

That is not unobstrusive javascript because behaviour and presentation are mixed. The `onclick` shouldn't be there in html and should be part of javascript itself not html.

With above example, you can go unobstrusive like this:

```
<input type="button" id="btn" />
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var el = document.getElementById('btn');
el.onclick = function(){
  alert('Test');
};
```

That time we have separated javascript from html with a very basic example.

**Note:**

There is more to unobstrusive javascript as can be checked out on wikipedia article.

Comment: Thanks for a great example but why is it bad to have onclick="alert('Test') in the html?

Comment: @Imran: For a number of reasons if you think about it. For easy portability, easy for others to finds things out, extendibility, etc.

Comment: That's not a great example, because it fails to provide "Progressive enhancement". If JS doesn't work, then you have a button which does nothing when clicked. To be unobtrusive either the button should be added to the DOM with JS (if the feature it provides is not needed for the page to work) or it should be a submit button with server side code to generate the message as a new page load if the JS fails.