# What is unobtrusive JavaScript in client-side validation scripts

Tags: javascript, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [What is Unobtrusive Javascript in layman terms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4478795/what-is-unobtrusive-javascript-in-layman-terms)

I refer a [site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171868.aspx#web) in which they mentioned as follows

> ASP.NET 4.5 includes the following new features:
>
> - Support for unobtrusive JavaScript in client-side validation scripts.

What does "unobtrusive JavaScript" mean?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript

Comment: The wikipedia article and question link both answer your question already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unobtrusive Javascript means it doesnt intefere with the markup (HTML).

E.g.

Obtrusive JS in the HTML:

```
<a onclick="myFunction()">My Link</a>
```

Unobtrusive JS:

In the HTML:

```
<a>My Link</a>
```

In the JS:

```
$('a').click(function() {
    //Code in here
);
```

Note in the unobtrusive example the JS could be entirely stored in a separate JS file.

Comment: HI cowls, i suggest you tidy the unobtrusive example.  not my -1 but an example with Anchor HTML and JS together isnt ideal.  js that queried the Document by id and had onclick or similar would be better dont you think ? Dont mix html and JS is the whole idea. Is there a why to highlight that separation with your example?

Comment: thanks Cowls,  btw the -1, can we see a comment with your view please ?