# Javascript not adding two string numbers using parseInt function

Tags: javascript, html

I have two **< div >** section having numbers inside. When number present in 1st **< div >** is clicked , 2nd  content should show twice the value of 1st **< div >**.

I used following code but **not** working.

```
<div id="left"><a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('right').innerHTML = (parseInt(document.getElementById('left').innerHTML) + parseInt(document.getElementById('left').innerHTML))">1</a></div>

<div id="right">1</div>
```

But the output is coming as

> **NaN**

Can somebody help with correct code ? Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't twice the value be `value*2` not `value*value` ?

Comment: I am doing value + value ; pls check the code again

Comment: If `parseInt(x)` is giving `NaN` then `NaN + y` is `y + NaN` is `NaN`.

Comment: @PaulS. So what is the correct function to use there ?

Comment: @logan I'm saying you're providing the wrong input, not using the wrong function.

Comment: please see the value of div2, its 1 ; so its not a string. its a number... <div id="right">1</div>

Comment: omg separate your javascript and html lol

Comment: @jayharris : why ? will it cause any problem ?

Comment: @logan no its for best practices and readability [read this question on unobtrusive javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4478795/what-is-unobtrusive-javascript-in-layman-terms) and [the wikipedia articule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The element `#left` contains the entire anchor, so you're getting all the HTML of the anchor back, and not just the number, which is why parseInt spits out NaN.

In other words:

```
document.getElementById('left').innerHTML
```

will return:

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('right').innerHTML = (parseInt(document.getElementById('left').innerHTML) + parseInt(document.getElementById('left').innerHTML))">1</a>
```

And when parsing that as an integer it returns NaN ?

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/K8dJM/)

You can solve it by doing:

```
<div id="left"><a href="#" onclick="calc(this); return false;">1</a></div>
<div id="right">1</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function calc(elem) {
        var val = parseInt(elem.innerHTML,10) * 2;
        document.getElementById('right').innerHTML = val;
    }
</script>
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/K8dJM/1/)

Comment: You can parse it as an Integer, it just gives you `NaN`. Also, I'd suggest using `.textContent` over `.innerHTML` for this task.

Comment: @PaulS. - well, yeah I suppose.

Comment: @PaulS. .parseInt(document.getElementById('left').textContent is working fine... Thanks