# Why isn't this onclick JavaScript call working?

Tags: javascript, function, onclick

HTML

```
<div id="test"></div>
<input type="button" value="Go" onclick="test()" />
```

JavaScript

```
function test() {
    alert("Test!");
}
```

Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/MVBrS/11/

Comment: `No wrap - in <head>`. http://jsfiddle.net/MVBrS/12/

Comment: That did it but what does the `No wrap - in <head>` do exactly?

Comment: The other options wrap the code in a closure so your functions won't be available in the global scope. The best way is to attach your events _in JavaScript_, not in the markup. Look for `addEventListener`.

Comment: So, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/MVBrS/18/

Comment: Yup. That's best practice.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at this one, it is about jsfiddle code frames separation:

[Inline event handler not working in JSFiddle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431351/simple-example-doesnt-work-on-jsfiddle)

Of course, if you were running the same code embedded on plain HTML it works normally, having the alerted popup appearing.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <script>
        function test() {
          alert("Test!");
        }
      </script>
     </head>
     <body>
       <div id="test"></div>
       <input type="button" value="Go" onclick="test()" />
     </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score -1):

when you do

```
onclick="test()"
```

as an attribute of the input element, you are setting the result of the call test() (in your case 'null') as the click event handler

you probably want to do this

```
onclick="test"
```

instead, which will set the actual 'test' function as the handler,

or even better, follow the following guidelines: [unbtrusive javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) or [unobtrusive JS (2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4478795/what-is-unobtrusive-javascript-in-layman-terms),.. you get the point ;)