# How can I put a java script variable into css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using it in a drop down menu system. on mouse hover on a link the image of a parent div got switched and on mouse out it reverts the image. this variable I am using in html. Is there a way I can put this variable in my css sheet and call through an id or class?

In `<li>` tag you can see the mouseover and mouseout, I want to give an class ot id to call this variable.

This is my html

```
<div onmouseover="changeImage(fashionSrc)" onmouseout="changeImage(fashionSrc1)">
    <h3>Casuals</h3>
</div>
<ul>
    <li onmouseover="changeImage(fashionSrc2)" onmouseout="changeImage(fashionSrc1)"><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li onmouseover="changeImage(fashionSrc3)" onmouseout="changeImage(fashionSrc1)"><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li onmouseover="changeImage(fashionSrc4)" onmouseout="changeImage(fashionSrc1)"><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
    <li onmouseover="changeImage(fashionSrc5)" onmouseout="changeImage(fashionSrc1)"><a href="#">Menu 4</a></li>
    <li onmouseover="changeImage(fashionSrc6)" onmouseout="changeImage(fashionSrc1)"><a href="#">Menu 5</a></li>
    <li onmouseover="changeImage(fashionSrc7)" onmouseout="changeImage(fashionSrc1)"><a href="#">Menu 6</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You'll have to be more clear in what it is you are looking to do, for we simply cannot understand what you are asking here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
onMouseOver = "this.src="../your_path/image1.png"; //or anything else
onMouseOut = "this.src="../your_path/image2.png"; //or anything else
```

Consider unobstrusive javascript, [link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4478795/what-is-unobtrusive-javascript-in-layman-terms) [link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8392374/difference-between-obtrusive-and-unobtrusive-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way I can put this variable in my css sheet and call
>   through an id or class?

No afaik. What you can do is modify the element's class and define those in your CSS. You should use the [:hover pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3ahover) instead of JS tricks in this case anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple way to create a menu with drop-down. try this.

HTML like this.

```
<div class="drop-down">
  <h2></h2>
  <ul>
    <li>Menu 1</li>
    ...
  </ul>
</div>
```

Style like this.

```
.drop-down {
  position:relative;
  height:40px;
}

.drop-down h2 {
  ... //Some style for heading
}

.drop-down ul{
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  top:40px; // Equal to drop-down height;
  left:0;
}

//Display the submenu, when hover
.drop-down:hover ul {
  display:block;
}
```